# Coriander legging

Tags: herbs

Should I continue growing this potted coriander now that it has started legging? I maybe have started too early in the winter and the sun just wasn’t plentiful enough. [image]

Answer (score 2):

Coriander needs several hours of full sunshine each day to grow properly. Trying to grow it indoors in winter without growing lights is a waste of time, as you just found out.

If you have a sunny enough window, you could try again indoors in May or June, or grow it outdoors either in a pot or in the ground.

You can sow it as late as September, to get leaves to harvest in winter.

Comment: Alternative: Add a grow lamp for now, harvest early. Then start over when you have more light.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will look into a grow lamp then.

Comment: Lower the soil temperature and give them more light.